# Configure data table item template slot dynamically

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, vuetify.js

I am trying to move the configuration of my data table header to my appsettings.json file.  I have that working but there are some fields that need to be formatted via a template.  For example, we store dates as unix timestamps so I have a method in my Vue component that formats that timestamp to the local time string.  Previously I just had a template for each header column to do this.  Since I am trying to make this more dynamic, I want to be able to format any date column as such.  I'm trying something as follows, but it's not working:

```
<v-data-table :items="inspections"
              ref="InspectionsDataTable"
              item-key="inspectionId"
              loading-text="Loading... Please wait."
              loader-height="80"
              fixed-header
              dense
              hide-default-footer
              :height="gridHeight"
              :calculate-widths="true"
              :server-items-length="totalRecords"
              :headers="headers"
              :hide-default-header="true"
              :options.sync="options"
              :expanded.sync="expanded">
  <template v-slot:header="{ props: { headers } }">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="header in headers"
            :key="header.value"
            :style="getHeaderStyle(header)"
            :v-show="header.show">
          <span :class="{sortable: header.sortable}"
                @click="headerClick(header)">
            {{header.text}}
          </span>
          <span v-show="options.sortBy[0] === header.value"
                :class="{rotate: options.sortDesc[0] === true}">&#x25bc;</span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </template>
  <template v-for="header in dateHeaders"
            v-slot:item[header.value]=" { item }">
    {{toDateTime(item[header.value])}}
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

...

```
dateHeaders() {
    if (this.gridConfig === undefined) return undefined;
    return this.headers.filter(f => f.dataType === 'date');
  },

toDateTime(unixTimestamp) {
        if (unixTimestamp === undefined) return undefined;
        return TimestampHelper.toDateTime(unixTimestamp).toLocaleString();
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working as such:

```
<template v-for="header in dateHeaders"
            v-slot:[`item.${header.value}`]="{item}">
    {{toDateTime(item[header.value])}}
  </template>
```